# Ruby on Rails - Devise Error: undefined local variable or method

Tags: devise, routes, ruby-on-rails-4

I have been checking on SO and the googles for a solution, but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.  I am trying to use the `after_sign_in_path_for` helper from Devise.  I have looked at the documentation on this helper [here](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Controllers/Helpers:after_sign_in_path_for).

But I am getting the following error upon submitting the sign in credentials:

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `dashboard_url' for #
<Devise::SessionsController:0x007fcc36079d88>):
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:27:in `after_sign_in_path_for'
```

Here's what I'm working with:

## config/routes.rb

```
My::Application.routes.draw do
  get "login/index"
  devise_for :users, path_names: {sign_in: "login"} do
    get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
  end
 get "dashboard/index"
 root :to => "login#index"
 get 'dashboard' => 'dashboard#index', as: :dashboard_url
 get ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
end
```

The path shows up in `rake routes` as the following:

## rake routes

```
  dashboard_url GET    /dashboard(.:format)                   dashboard#index
```

Any help would be appreciated!  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix it in your routes

`get 'dashboard' => 'dashboard#index', as: :dashboard`

Rake routes show your routes helpers without `_path` and `_url` suffixes appended.

Comment: Thanks Nick. I'm new to RoR and still haven't captured the concept of routes.

Answer (score 2):

ApplicationController.rb

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    users_dashboard_path
end
```

Routes.rb

```
namespace :users do
  get 'dashboard' => 'dashboard#index', as: :dashboard
end
```

**Note: I have created my Dashboard Controller inside Users folder created by Devise. (like this => 'users/dashboard_controller.rb')**
Hope this working example will help you